# Grep only a few number after some pattern in a string

Tags: java, string, grep

I have a xml file which look like this

```
<testsuite name="org.eclipse.app4mc.addon.multicore.cpurta.tests.CPURtaIATest" time="2.489" tests="1" errors="0" skipped="0" failures="0">
<testsuite name="org.eclipse.app4mc.addon.multicore.cpurta.tests.EventChainLatencyTest" time="0.491" tests="2" errors="0" skipped="0" failures="0">
<testsuite xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/xsd/surefire-test-report.xsd" name="org.eclipse.app4mc.addon.multicore.rta.tests.CommonUtilsTest" time="0.02" tests="16" errors="0" skipped="0" failures="0">
<testsuite xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/xsd/surefire-test-report.xsd" name="org.eclipse.app4mc.addon.multicore.rta.tests.RuntimeUtilTest" time="0" tests="0" errors="0" skipped="0" failures="0">
<testsuite xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/xsd/surefire-test-report.xsd" name="org.eclipse.app4mc.addon.multicore.rta.tests.BlockingTest" time="0.303" tests="4" errors="0" skipped="0" failures="0">
<testsuite xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/xsd/surefire-test-report.xsd" name="org.eclipse.app4mc.addon.multicore.rta.tests.GPUSchedulingTest" time="1.855" tests="2" errors="0" skipped="0" failures="0">
<testsuite xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/xsd/surefire-test-report.xsd" name="org.eclipse.app4mc.addon.multicore.rta.tests.ContentionTest" time="0.271" tests="2" errors="0" skipped="0" failures="0">
```

These are the 2nd line of maven surefire report (the xml one) fyi, got that after using this

```
find ./littleRTA/**/target/surefire-reports -name '*.xml' -exec awk 'NR==2' {} \; > totalText.txt`
```

in gitlab-ci

I want to fetch the number after the keywords `time`, `error`, `tests` etc in the end of the line and put them into a csv file so it would be like this in my csv

> 0.271, 2, 0, 0, 0

Or maybe just put them into a text file. Thinking about trying `grep` but the name of the file can contain any of those keyword

Comment: I think using regex would work much better for you here are some examples -> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131785/regex-that-would-grep-numbers-after-specific-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ awk -F'"' -v OFS=, '{print $(NF-9), $(NF-7), $(NF-5), $(NF-3), $(NF-1)}' file
2.489,1,0,0,0
0.491,2,0,0,0
0.02,16,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
0.303,4,0,0,0
1.855,2,0,0,0
0.271,2,0,0,0
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ed Morton indeed answer my problem with output the csv file. But @Nick Reed also show me how fetching the regex work look like, I barely know how to use awk so I thought by using grep to sort the data, then use awk to output to csv file would be okay too...Both big thanks to both of you anyway.

Got it done by this.

```
- find ./littleRTA/**/target/surefire-reports -name '*.xml' -exec awk 'NR==2' {} \; >> beforeGrep.txt
- awk -F'"' -v OFS=, '{print $(NF-9), $(NF-7), $(NF-5), $(NF-3), $(NF-1)}' beforeGrep.txt >> afterGrep.csv
```

Comment: If you change `awk 'NR==2'` to `awk 'NR==2{print; exit}'` then your `find` command would run faster as it'd stop processing each file after it prints the 2nd line. You could also change the whole thing to `find ./littleRTA/**/target/surefire-reports -name '*.xml' -exec awk -F'"' -v OFS=, 'NR==2{print $(NF-9), $(NF-7), $(NF-5), $(NF-3), $(NF-1); exit}' {} \; >> afterGrep.csv` and not need that intermediate `beforeGrep` file (you should probably be using `>` instead of `>>` btw).

Answer (score 0):

`grep` runs on regex, Java has regex libraries, and regex can process your request without too much difficulty! How about this?

`^.*time="([0-9\.]+)" tests="(\d+)" errors="(\d+)" skipped="(\d+)" failures="(\d+)".*$`

```regex
BREAKDOWN

^.*time="([0-9\.]+)" tests="(\d+)" errors="(\d+)" skipped="(\d+)" failures="(\d+)".*$

^                                                                                   $    between the start and end of the string
 .*                                                                               .*     get any number of any characters except newline
   time="          "                                                                     look for time= plus quote marks, literally
         (        )                                                                      capture...
          [0-9\.]+                                                                       ...one or more digits or a period, literally
                     tests="     "                                                       look for tests, equal sign, and quotes, around the next capture group:
                            (\d+)                                                        one or more digits
                                                                                         (this is repeated for the other parts, looking for a word
                                                                                         and then quotes, then getting the number inside of them)
```

The regex searches for the desired keywords, followed by an equal sign and quotes, before then getting the value inside the quotes. Even if the filenames contain the keywords, they won't contain equal signs and double quotes following in exactly the same pattern as you're trying to match. (If they do, you've probably got bigger problems on your hands, because I'm pretty sure those are illegal characters.)

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/8ATEMa/1)

Comment: Oh wow, never know that there is a website to test that. Thank you very very much Nick Reed

Comment: You're welcome! Java also has [built-in regex libraries](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm) *and* [xml parsing libraries.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm) There's plenty of ways to go about your task - good luck!

Comment: Hi there again...would you mind show me how does a full command look like...? I tried and it give tell me `grep: errors=(\d+): No such file or directory`...and also if you don't mind, could you guide me to output those into csv file or txt file too?

Comment: @Zero testing a regexp in some online tool just proves that the regexp works in that online tool, it doesn't prove that it'll work in any other tool. The particular regexp in this answer is also trying to identify capture groups for the data you want to print but grep has no facility to print specific capture groups, you need sed or awk for that. You were a bit hasty in accepting this answer and discouraging other people from posting alternative answers.

Comment: @Zero I would agree with @EdMorton here; if you're planning to do this with command line instead of java, `awk`is the better tool to use. His answer (and `awk` in general) is more suited to direct-to-file conversion. If you want to do it with Java, try using a regex library and some file I/O to open a file, read the data, search it, and then write it to another file.